# htaccess http to https redirect for www & sub domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, https

I currently have a redirect that works to redirect all HTTP pages to the corresponding HTTPS pages for the `http://www.` and the `http://` pages, as follows:

```
# redirect all pages to https://www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
# redirect http to https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

I also need to include a redirect for the sub-domain `http://my.` to go to `https://my.`

If I put a redirect in the .htaccess file for the sub domain, it is interfered with by the .htaccess file for www.

What changes do I need to make for the following to work:

- Redirect all `http://www.` and `http://` pages to their corresponding https pages
- Redirect all `http://my.` pages to their corresponding https pages

without one messing up the other.

Comment: I think someone might have voted me down one because I used http// in my question rather than http://.

I would like to let them know that this is because as a user without a rating of 10 or more I cannot post more than 2 links in the question.

Thanks for correcting it though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so the issue with your mod_rewrite is that the rewrite rule:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]`

will match anything that doesn't begin with www.

The syntax of this line is:

`RewriteCond {string to match} {regular expression to match} {other parameters}`

In your case, it says:

Match any URL whose hostname (`%{HTTP_HOST}`) does not (`!`) begin with (`^`) "www.". (The backslash before the period is because period has a special meaning in regular expressions -- it stands for "any character").

The [NC] at the end means to ignore capitalisation.

So, the first part of your .htaccess

```
# redirect all pages to https://www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

says:

Rewrite every URL whose host doesn't start with "www.", including "me.", by prepending "www.".

Obviously this will rewrite me.whatever.com to www.me.whatever.com.

What you need to do to fix it is add another match rule to exclude that case.

ie:
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^me\. [NC]`

So the full .htaccess should be:

```
# redirect all pages to https://www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^me\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
# redirect http to https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

So now the rewrite condition is:
If the hostname doesn't start with www. AND doesn't start with me., THEN prepend www.

Here's a nice tester that you can use to play with different solutions: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

And to learn how to write these files, first learn regular expressions; they're an essential part of any technologist's toolkit!

Good luck :)

Comment: That htaccess link looks wonderful. I'm going to give it a try out next time I have htaccess issues.

Comment: Nice one! and for general purpose regex play, https://regex101.com/ is my favourite

Comment: Excellent. Most of this worked, but I later discovered other factors - that there was another redirect in httpd.conf that I did not have access to, that caused a redirect loop.